# How to extract a human name in a string python

Tags: python, regex, pycharm, ocr

I have a string out of an OCR'ed image, and I need to find a way to extract human names from it. [here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocJnc.png) required to OCR, which comes out as:

```
From: Al Amri, Salim <salim.amri@gmail.com>

Sent: 25 August 2021 17:20

To: Al Harthi, Mohammed <mohd4.king@rihal.om>

Ce: Al hajri, Malik <hajri990@ocaa.co.om>; Omar, Naif <nnnn49@apple.com>

Subject: Conference Rooms Booking Details

Dear Mohammed,

As per our last discussion these are the available conference rooms available for booking along
with their rates for full day:

Room: Luban, available on 26/09/2021. Rate: $4540

Room: Mazoon, available on 04/12/2021 and 13/02/2022. Rate: $3000
Room: Dhofar. Available on 11/11/2021. Rate: $2500

Room: Nizwa. Available on 13/12/2022. Rate: $1200

   

Please let me know which ones you are interested so we go through more details.
Best regards,

Salim Al Amri
```

There are 4 names in total in the heading, and i am required to get the output:

```
names = 'Al Hajri, Malik', 'Omar, Naif', 'Al Amri, Salim', 'Al Harthy, Mohammed' #desired output
```

but I have no idea how to extract the names. I have tried RegEx and came up with:

```
names = re.findall(r'(?i)([A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][a-z][, ] [A-Z][a-z]+)', string) #regex to find names
```

which searches for a Capital letter, then a comma, then another word starting with a capital letter. it is close to the desired result but it comes out as:

```
names = ['Amri, Salim', 'Harthi, Mohammed', 'hajri, Malik', 'Omar, Naif', 'Luban, available', 'Mazoon, available'] #acutal result
```

I have thought of maybe using another string that extracts the room names and excludes them from the list, but i have no idea how to implement that idea. i am new to RegEx, so any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: For your human name extractor, will it be used only with inputs following the format described above? If so, RegEx is the way to go. If not, it becomes a much harder problem.

Comment: If you can guarantee that the header will include emails, one idea is to look for anything that appears next to a <...> expression (an email address)

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes it will always be next to an email. I will try that and share the results. thanks

Comment: "*which searches for a Capital letter, then a comma, then another word starting with a capital letter*" therefore it won't work correctly for `van Gogh, Vincent`

Comment: @ibarrond yes, it will only be used with the same inputs

Comment: Unless you absolutely **must** use RE, you'll probably find it easier and quicker to implement by parsing the string line-by-line, and isolating the relevant tokens. You also need to be careful of the "rules" that define where names could be in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding the excellent RE approach suggested by @JvdV, here's a step-by-step way in which you could achieve this:

```
OCR = """From: Al Amri, Salim <salim.amri@gmail.com>

Sent: 25 August 2021 17:20

To: Al Harthi, Mohammed <mohd4.king@rihal.om>

Ce: Al hajri, Malik <hajri990@ocaa.co.om>; Omar, Naif <nnnn49@apple.com>

Subject: Conference Rooms Booking Details

Dear Mohammed,

As per our last discussion these are the available conference rooms available for booking along
with their rates for full day:

Room: Luban, available on 26/09/2021. Rate: $4540

Room: Mazoon, available on 04/12/2021 and 13/02/2022. Rate: $3000
Room: Dhofar. Available on 11/11/2021. Rate: $2500

Room: Nizwa. Available on 13/12/2022. Rate: $1200

   

Please let me know which ones you are interested so we go through more details.
Best regards,

Salim Al Amri"""

names = []
for line in OCR.split('\n'):
    tokens = line.split()
    if tokens and tokens[0] in ['From:', 'To:', 'Ce:']: # Ce or Cc ???
        parts = line.split(';')
        for i, p in enumerate(parts):
            names.append(' '.join(p.split()[i==0:-1]))
print(names)
```

Comment: thank you very much. just to elaborate on the Ce or CC comment, the OCR read it as Ce instead of Cc. I could theoretically fix this by enlarging the text, but since it does not affect the rest of the code I just left it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the contents of your email, a reasonable approach might be to use:

```
[:;]\s*(.+?)\s*<
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/awpX7Y/1).

- `[:;]` - A (semi-)colon;
- `\s*` - 0+ (Greedy) whitespaces;
- `(.+?)` - A 1st capture group of 1+ (Lazy) characters;
- `\s*` - 0+ (Greedy) whitespaces;
- `<` - A literal '<'.

Note that I specifically use `(.+?)` to capture names since names are notoriously hard to match.

---

```
import re
s = """From: Al Amri, Salim <salim.amri@gmail.com>

Sent: 25 August 2021 17:20

To: Al Harthi, Mohammed <mohd4.king@rihal.om>

Ce: Al hajri, Malik <hajri990@ocaa.co.om>; Omar, Naif <nnnn49@apple.com>

Subject: Conference Rooms Booking Details

Dear Mohammed,

As per our last discussion these are the available conference rooms available for booking along
with their rates for full day:

Room: Luban, available on 26/09/2021. Rate: $4540

Room: Mazoon, available on 04/12/2021 and 13/02/2022. Rate: $3000
Room: Dhofar. Available on 11/11/2021. Rate: $2500

Room: Nizwa. Available on 13/12/2022. Rate: $1200

   

Please let me know which ones you are interested so we go through more details.
Best regards,

Salim Al Amri"""
print(re.findall(r'[:;]\s*(.+?)\s*<', s))
```

Prints:

```
['Al Amri, Salim', 'Al Harthi, Mohammed', 'Al hajri, Malik', 'Omar, Naif']
```